What are the phalasruti of the following stotras and mantras of dakshina Moorthy?
What are the phalasruti of the following mantras and stotras of dakshina Moorthy , also try to provide any reference to the answers.

dakshina Moorthy pancharatnam
Sri dakshina Moorthy ashtakam
Sri dakshina Moorthy mantra stavanam

